# Subsample a matrix by selection locations with specific values within a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, subsampling

I'm have to use R instead of Matlab and I'm new to it.

I have a large array of data repeating like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10...

I need to find the locations where values equal to 1, 4, 7, 10 are found to create a sample using those locations.

In this case it will be position(=corresponding value) 1(=1) 4(=4) 7(=7) 10(=10) 11(=1) 14(=4) 17(=7) 20(=10) and so on.

in MatLab it would be y=find(ismember(x,[1, 4, 7, 10 ])),
Please, help! Thanks, Pavel

Comment: Maybe `which(x %in% c(1,4,7,10))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this?

```
foo <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
bar <- c(1, 4, 7, 10)
which(foo %in% bar)
#> [1]  1  4  7 10 11 14 17 20
```

@[nicola](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3987294/nicola), feel free to copy my answer and get the recognition for your answer, simply trying to close answered questions.

Answer (score 0):

The %in% operator is what you want. For example,

```
# data in x
targets <- c(1, 4, 7, 10)
locations <- x %in% targets
# locations is a logical vector you can then use:
y <- x[locations]
```

There'll be an extra step or two if you wanted the row and column indices of the locations, but it's not clear if you do. (Note, the logicals will be in column order).